# Return list in python

Tags: python

I have a working code:

```
def after_tasks(visits):
   return {task: {name for name, ta in visits if ta == task} for name, task in visits}
```

And the code returns something in the format like: `{"taskexample": {"something",...}}` 
But i want a code to return something like `{{"something",..}}`, without "taskexample": on the beginning. 
How do i achive that? Plus it needs to be written in one line like the code above.

The visits structure is:

```
   [("Ana", "coffe"), 
     ("Berta", "coffe"), 
     ("Cilka", "exercise"),
     ("Dani", "doctor")]
```

Comment: You are returning a dictionary

Comment: How is your 'visits' structure look like?

Comment: added the visits structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Understanding and using `dict`

Your function `after_task`, as it is currently written, returns a `dict` (for "dictionary"). This is a standard python class which associates *keys* and *values*. You can iterate over a dict using `.keys()`, `.values()` or `.items()`:

```py
d = {'a': 'Alice'; 'b': 'Bob'; 'c': 'Chong'}

for k in d.keys():
  print(k)

for v in d.values():
  print(v)

for k,v in d.items():
  print('{}: {}'.format(k, v))
```

### Fixing your code

If I understand your question correctly, your problem is that your function is returning a dict, but you want to return simply the list of values in the dict, rather than associations key:value.

You can do that with `d.values()`:

```py
def after_tasks(visits):
   d = {task: {name for name, ta in visits if ta == task} for name, task in visits}
   return list(d.values())

print(after_tasks([("Ana", "coffe"), ("Berta", "coffe"), ("Cilka", "exercise"), ("Dani", "doctor")]))
# [{'Ana', 'Berta'}, {'Cilka'}, {'Dani'}]
```

### Completely different code for the same problem

This is another suggestion using `itertools.groupby`.

```py
import itertools
import operator

def after_tasks(visits):
  return [[name for task,name in g] for k,g in itertools.groupby(sorted([(k,v) for v,k in visits]), key=operator.itemgetter(0))]

print(after_tasks([("Ana", "coffe"), ("Berta", "coffe"), ("Cilka", "exercise"), ("Dani", "doctor")]))
# [['Ana', 'Berta'], ['Dani'], ['Cilka']]
```

### Relevant documentation

- [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict);
- [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby);
- [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter);